# Is it possible to dump local variables value in VEH or SEH exception handler?

Tags: exception, seh

Is it possible to dump local variables value in VEH or SEH exception handler?
In the exception context, we can get the registers SS,SP,BP... Can I get the local vairable value by these registers? and how?

If we return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION in the exception handler, the function will continue execution, the local variables still in memory(stack) when the exception handler running? Can I retrieve the local variables by ReadProcessMemory() in the exception handler?

Update:
Can I get full dump in the exception handler and search the local variable value in the dump file? I can know part of the variable value.

Comment: Not exactly.  You need debug info to know where the local variables are located.  But this can only work reliably in a non-optimized build.

Comment: Thanks Hans. When running into the exception handler, is the function stack still there (local variables are stored in stack, right) or has been destroyed? And how the program retrieve the local variable value if EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION returned and continue execution? Can I retrieve the values just like that?

Comment: If you are using VS2013+ I'd recommend to compile using [/Zo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn785163(v=vs.120).aspx) switch that will add more information about local variables to PDB files. Once you'll open dump in WinDbg you can view locals using `x` command.

Comment: thank you ge0rdi, I will try it.